# How to create hierarchical data frame using list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I have the following list of dictionaries that i want to flatten using python. The data is originally from xero and it looks like below:

Here is my sample data that is pulled using API:

```
my_dict = [{'RowType': 'Section', 'Title': 'Income', 'Rows': []},{'RowType': 'Section', 'Title': 'Income from Rents', 'Rows': []},
 {'RowType': 'Section',
  'Title': 'Rent Received',
  'Rows': [{'RowType': 'Row',
    'Cells': [{'Value': 'Contract Rent',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '5',
        'Id': 'account'},
       {'Value': '5', 'Id': 'groupID'}]},
     {'Value': '721093.92',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '5',
        'Id': 'account'},
       {'Value': '5', 'Id': 'groupID'}]}]},
   {'RowType': 'Row',
    'Cells': [{'Value': 'Rent  - Carparks',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '95',
        'Id': 'account'}]},
     {'Value': '3523.33',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '95',
        'Id': 'account'}]}]},
   {'RowType': 'Row',
    'Cells': [{'Value': 'Vacant Tenancies',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '53',
        'Id': 'account'}]},
     {'Value': '-22226.50',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '53',
        'Id': 'account'}]}]},
   {'RowType': 'SummaryRow',
    'Cells': [{'Value': 'Total Rent Received'}, {'Value': '702390.75'}]}]},
 {'RowType': 'Section',
  'Title': 'Rent Reductions',
  'Rows': [{'RowType': 'Row',
    'Cells': [{'Value': 'COVID-19 Rent reduction',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '40',
        'Id': 'account'}]},
     {'Value': '-132478.03',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '40',
        'Id': 'account'}]}]},
   {'RowType': 'Row',
    'Cells': [{'Value': 'Rent Holiday',
      'Attributes': [{'Value': '4d',
        'Id': 'account'}]},

         {'Value': '-14451.58',
          'Attributes': [{'Value': '4d',
            'Id': 'account'}]}]},
       {'RowType': 'SummaryRow',
        'Cells': [{'Value': 'Total Rent Reductions'}, {'Value': '-146929.61'}]}]}]
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
          Name        Amount    Hierarchy_level_3   Hierarchy_level_1   Hierarchy_level_2
0   Contract Rent   721093.92   Rent Received            Income        Income from Rents
1   Rent - Carparks 3523.33     Rent Receive             Income        Income from Rents
2   Vacant Tenancies -22226.50  Rent Received            Income        Income from Rents
3   Total Rent Received 702390.75           
4   COVID-19 Rent reduction -132478.03  Rent Reduction   Income        Income from Rents
     .                .              .                       .          .          .
     .                .              .                       .          .           .
```

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this please? The sample data here is how the format I am getting from the api. Not sure how to flatten this file. I am relatively newer to Python.

Comment: **Off-topic:** Beware of posting company restricted / confidential data on SO, i.e. the internet. It may (or may not) cause you problems with your employer. Of course, the data you post may be entirely your own property, I wouldn't know(?). You could replace the numbers with fictive data and the keys (cell names) with some arbitrary but still relevant names.

Comment: The ids are encrypted and its my personal data as well. It shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `Hierarchy_level_3` for line `4` in your example is `Rent Received` and not `Rent Reduction`, and that you have a level 4 hierarchy in your example, here is a solution. I added the level number and level name because I think these could be more useful than the "hierarchy levels" but feel free to remove th

```
import pandas as pd
hierarchy = {f'Hierarchy_level_{i+1}': d['Title'] for i, d in enumerate(my_dict)}
all_data = []

for level, d in enumerate(my_dict):
    for row in d['Rows']:
        cells = row['Cells']
        all_data.append({
            'Name': cells[0]['Value'],
            'Amount': cells[1]['Value'],
            'Level': level,
            'Level_name': hierarchy[f'Hierarchy_level_{level+1}'],
            **hierarchy
        })
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
```

Output:

```
                   Name      Amount  Level       Level_name Hierarchy_level_1  Hierarchy_level_2 Hierarchy_level_3 Hierarchy_level_4
0            Contract Rent   721093.92      2    Rent Received            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received   Rent Reductions
1         Rent  - Carparks     3523.33      2    Rent Received            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received   Rent Reductions
2         Vacant Tenancies   -22226.50      2    Rent Received            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received   Rent Reductions
3      Total Rent Received   702390.75      2    Rent Received            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received   Rent Reductions
4  COVID-19 Rent reduction  -132478.03      3  Rent Reductions            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received   Rent Reductions
5             Rent Holiday   -14451.58      3  Rent Reductions            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received   Rent Reductions
6    Total Rent Reductions  -146929.61      3  Rent Reductions            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received   Rent Reductions
```

--- Edit
Since only 3 levels of hierarchy are required:

```
import pandas as pd
hierarchy = {f'Hierarchy_level_{i+1}': d['Title'] for i, d in enumerate(my_dict)}
all_data = []

for level, d in enumerate(my_dict):
    for row in d['Rows']:
        cells = row['Cells']
        all_data.append({
            'Name': cells[0]['Value'],
            'Amount': cells[1]['Value'],
            'Hierarchy_level_1': hierarchy[f'Hierarchy_level_1'],
            'Hierarchy_level_2': hierarchy[f'Hierarchy_level_2'],
            'Hierarchy_level_3': hierarchy[f'Hierarchy_level_{level+1}'],
        })
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
```

Output:

```
Name      Amount Hierarchy_level_1  Hierarchy_level_2 Hierarchy_level_3
0            Contract Rent   721093.92            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received
1         Rent  - Carparks     3523.33            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received
2         Vacant Tenancies   -22226.50            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received
3      Total Rent Received   702390.75            Income  Income from Rents     Rent Received
4  COVID-19 Rent reduction  -132478.03            Income  Income from Rents   Rent Reductions
5             Rent Holiday   -14451.58            Income  Income from Rents   Rent Reductions
6    Total Rent Reductions  -146929.61            Income  Income from Rents   Rent Reductions
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. This is really helpful. Just one problem though, Rent Reduction should be hierarchy_level_3 not level hierarchy_level_4. In general, there should be only three levels of hierarchies maximum.

Comment: You can add `"Hierarchy_level_3": hierarchy[f'Hierarchy_level_{level+1}']` after `**hierarchy`, that will override level 3 with the correct level

Comment: omg I cant thank you enough for this. Literally it has taken me hours and hours to solve this. Thanks heaps. :)

Comment: one question for you though, how can I include the account ids if i want to show the ids in the data frame? can you please help? `

Comment: You can add `'AccountId': cells[0].get('Attributes', [{'Value': 'N/A'}])[0]['Value']`